# Need help adding numbers everytime a JCheckBox or a JButton is checked off

Tags: java, numbers, jcheckbox, jradiobutton

Beef Button, Vegan Button and the others all have the prices beside them when opened. The others at the bottom (Mustard Ketchup and the other condiment also have the numbers) I just need to know how to add numbers to int TotalArgent out of all the 3 checkboxes and 3 JRadioButtons

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Shopping
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lister v1.0");

    int TotalArgent = 0;
    int BeefArgent = 15;
    int PouletArgent = 20;
    int VeganArgent = 70;
    int KetchupArgent = 1;
    int MoutardArgent = 2;
    int CorcnichonsArgent = 17;
    JPanel entreePanel = new JPanel();
    final ButtonGroup entreeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton radioButtonBeef;
    JRadioButton radioButtonVegan;
    JRadioButton radioButtonPoulet;
    entreePanel.add(radioButtonBeef = new JRadioButton("Boeuf 15$"));
    radioButtonBeef.setActionCommand("Boeuf");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButtonBeef);
    entreePanel.add(radioButtonPoulet = new JRadioButton("Poulet 20$"));
    radioButtonPoulet.setActionCommand("Poulet");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButtonPoulet);
    entreePanel.add(radioButtonVegan = new JRadioButton("Végétarien 70$", true));
    radioButtonVegan.setActionCommand("Végétarien");
    entreeGroup.add(radioButtonVegan);

    final JPanel condimentsPanel = new JPanel();
    condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Ketchup (1$)"));
    condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Moutard (2$)"));
    condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Cornichons (17$)"));

    JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton orderButton = new JButton("Place la commande, recoivre votre totale");
    orderPanel.add(orderButton);

    Container content = frame.getContentPane(); // unnecessary in 5.0+
    content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    content.add(entreePanel);
    content.add(condimentsPanel);
    content.add(orderPanel);

    orderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        String entree =
          entreeGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();
        System.out.println( "total: " + TotalArgent + "$\n" + entree + " sandwich");
        Component[] components = condimentsPanel.getComponents();
        for ( Component c : components ) {
          JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox)c;
          if (cb.isSelected())
            System.out.println("With " +  cb.getText());
        }
      }
    });

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    frame.setSize(400, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that when Moutard is clicked, TotalArgent value must be increased by 2 and like so?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do this (Comments are in the code):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Shopping
{
    // Have all these static so you don't have to create a Shopping instance
    static int TotalArgent = 0;
    static int BeefArgent = 15;
    static int PouletArgent = 20;
    static int VeganArgent = 70;
    static int KetchupArgent = 1;
    static int MoutardArgent = 2;
    static int CorcnichonsArgent = 17;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lister v1.0");
        JPanel entreePanel = new JPanel();
        final ButtonGroup entreeGroup = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton radioButtonBeef;
        JRadioButton radioButtonVegan;
        JRadioButton radioButtonPoulet;
        entreePanel.add(radioButtonBeef = new JRadioButton("Boeuf 15$"));
        radioButtonBeef.setActionCommand("Boeuf");
        entreeGroup.add(radioButtonBeef);
        entreePanel.add(radioButtonPoulet = new JRadioButton("Poulet 20$"));
        radioButtonPoulet.setActionCommand("Poulet");
        entreeGroup.add(radioButtonPoulet);
        entreePanel.add(radioButtonVegan = new JRadioButton("Végétarien 70$", true));
        radioButtonVegan.setActionCommand("Végétarien");
        entreeGroup.add(radioButtonVegan);

        final JPanel condimentsPanel = new JPanel();
        condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Ketchup (1$)"));
        condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Moutard (2$)"));
        condimentsPanel.add(new JCheckBox("Cornichons (17$)"));

        JPanel orderPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton orderButton = new JButton("Place la commande, recoivre votre totale");
        orderPanel.add(orderButton);

        Container content = frame.getContentPane(); // unnecessary in 5.0+
        content.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        content.add(entreePanel);
        content.add(condimentsPanel);
        content.add(orderPanel);

        orderButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                // reset the total back to zero
                TotalArgent = 0;
                String entree = entreeGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand();

                // determine which sandwich you have and set total accordingly
                if (entree.equals("Boeuf"))
                {
                    TotalArgent += BeefArgent;
                }
                else if (entree.equals("Poulet"))
                {
                    TotalArgent += PouletArgent;
                }
                else if (entree.equals("Végétarien"))
                {
                    TotalArgent += VeganArgent;
                }

                // Print the sandwich and total
                System.out.println(entree + " sandwich (" + TotalArgent + "$)");
                Component[] components = condimentsPanel.getComponents();
                for (Component c : components)
                {
                    JCheckBox cb = (JCheckBox) c;
                    if (cb.isSelected())
                    {
                        String txt = cb.getText();
                        System.out.println(" - With " + txt);

                        // add to the total what condiments they checked
                        if (txt.equals("Ketchup (1$)"))
                        {
                            TotalArgent += 1;
                        }
                        if (txt.equals("Moutard (2$)"))
                        {
                            TotalArgent += 2;
                        }
                        if (txt.equals("Cornichons (17$)"))
                        {
                            TotalArgent += 17;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Print out the total
                System.out.println("total: " + TotalArgent + "$");
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```